# Convert a string of comma separated values into values for mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am writing a stored procedure for mysql. I am using xampp localhost with mariadb.

The stored procedure receives an integer ID, and finds the string based on the ID frem the database. This string contains a list of numbers, seperated by commas.

I need to use this string of numbers for the IN clause in my SQL query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test(IN id INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE clist VARCHAR(255);

SELECT clists INTO clist
FROM camp 
WHERE cid = id ;
```

Now clist, a varchar variable contans a list of values like 4,6,8 in a string.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT  email
FROM table
WHERE ( col1 IN (clist) OR  col2 IN (clist)
```

so in mysql, the query becomes like this, and fetches only a single ID  of 4.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT  email
FROM table
WHERE ( col1 IN ('4,6,8') OR  col2 IN ('4,6,8')
```

I want it to become

```
SELECT  DISTINCT  email
FROM table
WHERE ( col1 IN (4,6,8) OR  col2 IN (4,6,8)
```

My question is - How do I remove the single quotes from the string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It might be simplest (nastiest) to use FIND_IN_SET

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(col1, clist) > 0 OR FIND_IN_SET(col2, clist) > 0
```

Comment: `>0` is excess in MySQL/MariaDB. Excess compare and no profit.

Comment: I've always preferred to be explicit rather than rely on falsy/truthy; for me the profit is in the understanding of the code. `WHERE x>0` is pretty clearly boolean, self documenting and obvious how to modify it to flip the logic, `WHERE x` requires the developer to know that the db concerned runs supports truthy/falsy, that whatever is output is compatibly truthy/falsy, and it doesn't transport well to other databases/programming languages. If it turns a 10 minute query into a 3 second one, then fine.. but for me there are more detractors than attractors